# Any idea why the maven-deploy-plugin does not offer a login/password command line option? (or am i blind?)

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm trying to create a script to 'mavenize' a set of libraries. In order to make them available directly from an artifactory repository, i wanted the script to run the deploy command for each of my libs.
But i cannot seem to find the login+password command lines options; is the settings.xml file the only option to specify them ?

Comment: What's the problem with settings.xml? You specify credentials once and use them for as long as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the username and password in the URL:

```
http://username:password@hostname:port/path
```